# What is command to run postgresql in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

The command to run psql in ubuntu 20.04.
psql command is not working well. How to create database also in ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 4):

The First command you will fire from your ubuntu terminal 
`sudo -i -u postgres` 
Then you can fire command 
`psql` 
 to go into postgres console.
Then you can create database.

 `CREATE DATABASE mydb`

Answer (score 0):

- Check service status and start, stop or restart:

sudo service postgresql `command` (status, start, stop, restart)

e.g.

```
sudo service postgresql status

sudo service postgresql start
```

- Login:

Default: sudo -u postgres psql

Details: sudo -u `username` psql `database name`

e.g.

```
sudo -u postgres mydb
```

- Create Database:

Create database `database name`;

e.g.

```
Create database mydb;
```

- View all databases:

To see all databases

```
\l
```

Comment: How about when you do not have the option of using systemd or service ?